# faster way to check list on membership multiple values

Tags: python-2.7

I want to test if multiple values have membership on a list, but the script is really slow.
What i tried so far:

```
list1 = [10,20,35,45,67,88,99]

for x in list1:
    if 9<x<11:
        for x in list1:
            if 34<x<39:
                for x in list1:
                    if 87<x<90:
                        print "YEAH"
```

Comment: It's slow because it does way too much work than it needs to. You should break your `foreach` cycles when you clearly obtained what you wanted from it. See [there](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: can you give me some help with the syntax? because when i break the loop(s) it won't work anymore....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to finish iteration once all your conditions are satisfied.

There might be cleverer ways to solve it, but the simplest I can think of is keeping track of all conditions' results, and breaking as soon as they all are `True`. For example:

```
list = [10, 20, 35, 45, 67, 88, 99, 0]
// there we will keep track of each test
cond1 = False
cond2 = False
cond3 = False

// Each of the conds will become True and will keep that value.
for x in list:
  cond1 = cond1 or (9 < x < 11)
  cond2 = cond2 or (34 < x < 39)
  cond3 = cond3 or (87 < x < 90)

  if cond1 and cond2 and cond3:
  // once all of them become True, we know what we want and can break the loop
    print "YEAH"
    break
```

Comment: FYI:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @ErikPaul, accepting is not the same as upvoting. Please see [this meta answer about accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)